# XE3 Metropolis app and Pull Down/Swipe down to close?

Tags: windows, delphi, gesture

Does anyone have a custom gesture for XE3 Metropolis apps to emulate the windows 8 swipe down/pull down with the mouse to close an application ?

XE3 only has right click/swipe up with a close button.

Thanks